# Promise.all() not receiving data if a promise isn't resolved

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm building a javascript widget that will load an iframe on to a page but to prevent the iframe from loading each time it's requested, an API lookup is required first to check that the `devices` that are being requested to load inside the iframe actually exist in the database.

The issue I'm having is that if an item in `products` doesn't exist in the database (which is very likely to happen) then that promise won't be resolved and in turn stops `Promise.all(promises).then()...` from returning `data` and I need this `data` array to pass the resolved devices into the iframe.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function sendAPIRequest (product) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        var url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/product_availability?__url_path_param=';

        var xhr = createAPIRequest('GET', url + product);

        if (!xhr) {
            return;
        }

        xhr.onload = function () {

            if (xhr.status == 200) {

                resolve(product);

            } else {

                reject(Error(xhr.statusText));

            }

        };

        xhr.onerror = function () {

            reject(Error('Error fetching data...'));

        };

        xhr.send();


    });

}


function formatProductName (product) {

    return product.replace(/ /g,"+").toLowerCase();

}


function getProducts () {

    var promises = [];

    for (var i in products) {

        promises.push(sendAPIRequest(formatProductName(products[i].product_name)));

    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(function (data) {

        console.log(data);

    }).catch(function (err) {

        console.log(err);

    });


}

getProducts();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Promise.all().done` is called when all promises have been resolved. You're rejecting some of the promises.

Either implement the `fail` or *always* resolve, with either a success or error value. This essentially moves your error handling down the chain.

```
if (xhr.status == 200) {
    resolve({ status: "ok", product: product });
} else {
    resolve({ status: "fail" });
}
```

You could also consider that a request for a non existing product succeeds and return an error body instead of the product data.